# Tor Browser import SSL certificate

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ssl

How import SSL cert in Tor Browser?
In Firefox I import my self signed cert in Setting -> Advanced -> Certificates -> Authorities. In TB I can't add cert as in FF, because if I add a cert it is not added.

I copy profiles from FF to TB, but nothing happends. TB ignores the certificates database (cert8.db, key3.db) from my profile.
Any ideas?

Comment: Problem sloved by changing in about:config

Comment: security.nocertdb true -> false
If you use sekf signed SSL cert, generated with option -sha256 , change also
security.pki.sha1_enforcement_level 2 -> 0 (not recommended by) or regenerate with -sha512.

Comment: Which system? If you've solved the problem, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The OP gave the answer in the comments. I'll add the answer for completeness:

Tor Browser has set `security.nocertdb` in `about:config` to true. This means that the intermediate certificate store is only in memory.  If you change this value to false, it will be possible to add new certificates.

Comment: IMHO it can be a possibility for data leak and fingerprinting. The possible attack vector is: using custom certs we can trick browser to load ssl-ciphered content with a client certificate previously imported. Also there's a possibility to elaborate JS and try to open different HTTPS urls and see if it will be valid, and if it will be - then the cert imported can indicate a group of users at least. For second attack vector we need multiple "import me" SSL certificate spots. But it's just a hypothetical screinario